# Make Directories Using Variables From Array (in Bash)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make directories using a variable in the directory name from a variables in an array, but it doesn't seem to concatenate the streams like I thought they would. I've tried a couple different ways.

I'm trying to get three directories named:
test_6_bash_with_directory, test_8_bash_with_directory, test_10_bash_with_directory

```
variable=`seq 6 2 10`

for i in "${variable[@]}"
do
   :
   directory_name="./test_${i}_bash_with_directory"
   mkdir $directory_name
   echo $i
done
```

This gives me three directories test_6, 8 and 10_bash_with_directory. Replacing ${i} with ${variable} has the same result.

I'd also tried having the `mkdir` call in the same line as the directory concatenation:

```
mkdir "./test_${i}_bash_with_directory"
```

and I got one directory called test_6?8?10_bash_with_directory

So, how do I write this correctly? Thank you for replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `variable` is a string, not an array.  You want:

```
variable=(`seq 6 2 10`)

for i in "${variable[@]}"
do
   directory_name="./test_${i}_bash_with_directory"
   mkdir $directory_name
   echo $i
done
```

Note the `(...)` around your sequence of values.

Comment: Eventually, since it is Bash: `variable=({6..10..2})` and `mkdir -p -- "$directory_name"`. Well the bracket expression or the `seq` command could be replaced by its constants `variable=(6 8 10)`.

Comment: So the reason I wanted to use a range of variables is because I'm later hoping to run a program with a different parameter, and then make a directory with that parameter in the name for the output of that program, so I want to keep the range array if possible